# How do I use Singleton in Dagger 1.x?

Tags: java, android, dagger

I read Christian Gruber's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447531/singletons-in-dagger-1-x/17453003#17453003) and I started wondering how to use Application-wide Singletons.
In my application I have a class `DBHelper`, which main purpose is holding the keys to my database. I have also many (at least two) different DAOs. 
Now - I don't see a reason why would my several Activities/classes need more than just a single instance of DAO. What's more, why would a DAO need an instance of `DBHelper` just for itself? I'm pretty sure they can share, especially I don't predict a situation when both DAOs would want to perform some operation on my database at the same time. So let's see some classes:

- `DBHelper`

  ```
  @Singleton
  public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        //some not relevant configuration stuff
        private Context context;

        @Inject
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
             this.context = context;
        }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //db.execSQL, creating tables and stuff
       }

       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //dropping tables, creating a new one
            onCreate(db);
       }
  }
  ```
- example of `DAO`

  ```
      public interface SomeDataDAO {
          void hai();
      }

      public class SomeDataDAOImpl implements SomeDataDAO {
           private DBHelper dbHelper;

           public SomeDataDAOImpl(DBHelper dbHelper){
                 this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
           }
           @Override
           public void hai() {
                SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dbHelper.doSomeDatabaseStuff()
           }
      }
  ```
- `SomeDataModule`

  ```
  @Module(
          injects = { MainActivity.class, SomeServiceImpl.class }
          )
  public class SomeDataModule {
        private Context appContext;

        @Provides @Singleton
        public SomeDataDAO provideSomeDataDao(DBHelper dbHelper){
              return new SomeDataDAOImpl(dbHelper);
        }

        @Provides @Singleton
        public ISomeService provideSomeService(SomeServiceImpl impl){
               return impl;
        }

        @Provides
        public Context getAppContext(){
               return this.appContext;
        }
        public SomeDataModule(){
               this.appContext = MainActivity.getAppContext();
        }
  }
  ```
- Now let's see two examples of dependency consumers

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
      @Inject
      SomeDataDAO someDataDAO;
      private ObjectGraph objectGraph;
      @Inject
      ISomeService someService;
      private static Context appContext;


      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           appContext = getApplicationContext();
           objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(SomeDataModule.class);
           objectGraph.inject(this);
           someService.doSomeStuff();
      }

     public static Context getAppContext() {
           return appContext;
     }
  }
  ```

  ```
  public class SomeServiceImpl implements ISomeService {
      private ObjectGraph objectGraph;
      @Inject public SomeDataDAO someDataDAO;

      public SomeServiceImpl(){
          objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(GraphDataModule.class);
          objectGraph.inject(this);
      }

      public void doSomeStuff(){
           someDataDAO.hai();
      }

  }
  ```

It works, however when I `inject(this)` twice, Dagger obviously creates me two instances of `DBHelper` as it thinks "One Singleton fon one graph instance". How do I wrap my `SomeDataModule` in `ApplicationModule`, so I have only one instance of `DBHelper` in the entire app? Adding `@Singleton` to `DBHelper` unfortunately was not enough.

Comment: If you have to go singleton, why not use a Global class with static members and methods?

Comment: @KristyWelsh I'm learning Android & Dagger. Even if in this particular case class with static members and methods could be better, I'd like to know how to achieve my goal with dependency injection, especially when I have quite easy example right now. By the way, is it even a proper design pattern? I don't think I have ever came across such approach. I met class with static fields giving constants, SQLs and so on, but never distributing DAOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy, short and the answer which solves a minor design flaw and with that your problem is the following. Instead of creating a new `ObjectGraph` to inject the `SomeDataDAO` instance in your `SomeServiceImpl`, you really should pass the `SomeDataDAO` to your constructor. That is actually what dependency injection typically means: use the constructor of some object to inject its dependencies:

```
public class SomeServiceImpl implements ISomeService {

    private final SomeDataDAO someDataDAO;

    @Inject
    public SomeServiceImpl(SomeDataDAO someDataDAO){
        this.someDataDAO = someDataDAO;
    }

    public void doSomeStuff(){
         someDataDAO.hai();
    }
}
```

Now this is where the magic happens. Notice the `@Inject` annotation for the constructor? It tells Dagger to use this constructor whenever an instance of `SomeServiceImpl` is requested, and queries the `ObjectGraph` for its parameters.

So when you've got this `Provides` method below, Dagger already knows that `SomeServiceImpl` depends on `SomeDataDAO`, and uses your `provideSomeDataDAO` method to provide that instance. And, hey, it's a singleton, so this is the exact same instance as any other instance of `SomeDataDAO` retrieved by this `ObjectGraph`!

```
  @Provides @Singleton
  public ISomeService provideSomeService(SomeServiceImpl impl){
         return impl;
  }
```

---

In fact, you don't want to use `ObjectGraph.inject(...)` too often, you actually want to use the above methods. There are cases however, where **you don't decide what the constructor looks like**. In Android for example, these are `Activity` and `View` classes, amongst others. For these special cases, `ObjectGraph.inject` was created, so you can still inject your dependencies using Dagger.

Final note: In `SomeServiceImpl` I have made the `someDataDAO` `private`. As you probably know, this is the preferred way to handle instance fields, and using injectable constructors enables this.

*<sub>Turns out this answer wasn't that short at all :O)</sub>*

Comment: [This](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs) is an example of how multiple modules can be used by the way.